# How to copy 5TB mongodb to a new machine within LAN

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I've tried:

1. SCP the (custom) DB directory from old machine to new machine - didn't work. Mongo complained of corrupt wiredTiger files
2. Ran mongodump and mongorestore - took about 5 times as long. The process was interrupted by someone who thought it'd finished, so missed a small amount of data
3. Realised 1. didn't work due to mongo not shutting down properly first.

Tried again, results in the following error:

> 2017-05-20T17:12:04.407+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (24) [1495296724:407111][46215:0x7f7bf304bb80], file:collection-299--5136948165504185516.wt, session.open_cursor: /home/myuser/mymongodir/data/db//collection-299--5136948165504185516.wt:
>
> Too many open files
> 2017-05-20T17:12:04.407+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError 24: Too many open files at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 69`

Comment: Did you try to run `ulimit -a` or something similar?

Comment: Post an answer, and I'll approve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to run:

```
ulimit -a
```

It will gives you the current open limit, you can then increase it accordingly using the `-n` option, which will increase the limit of your open files, allowing mongo to run safely.

Comment: `ulimit -a` will give print the open file limit. `ulimit -n 2048` will increase the open file limit (in this case to 2048).